# DBContext Query Optimization Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, dbcontext

Just a newbie here, We are starting a new Project,
Now my question, We are using entity framework dbcontext.
Is there way or best practice to minimize the select statement ,
for e.g context.tbEmployee.where(p=>p.name=='test').tolist()
the issue here is that, It picks up all the column even i don't
need the other columns, I know you would tell that specify the column that you need
but my issue is that not every time we people are very intricate with the codes
Just want to have a suggestion or best practice on what to do.
Should i use a Model then map to the Entity tables
what do you suggest?

Just a suggestion or best practice or what pattern to use on how  minimize the full select statement

Comment: Use the “Select” function to create a projection of only the fields you want.

Comment: The database server is still going to have to read most (if not all) of a records' fields/columns anyway, so using a minimal `SELECT` column list won't necessarily be as helpful as you might think - also, EF only supports using `.Select( r => new { } )` with `new {}` anonymous-types and not entities, which limits their applicability. (Reducing the column-set _does_ help with things like memory-allocation within complex queries, but EF does not support overly complex queries (e.g. OLAP, recursive CTEs, window-functions, etc) - if you're generating reports then consider doing it directly in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

As Matthew already suggested, you can use the Select() function to reduce the queried columns.

The easiest way is to get a anonymous type. For example if you just want the Id and the Name of your Employee, you could write the following:

```
var persons = context.tbEmployee.Where( p=> p.name == "test")
                                .Select(p => new {Id = p.Id, Name = p.Name})
                                .ToList()
```

Then you can access the Name with `persons.First().Name`

You could go event further and declare a Type for that "record"

```
public class NamedId
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

And then return a list of that type

```
var persons = context.tbEmployee.Where(p=> p.name == "test")
                                .Select(p=> new NamedId {Id = p.Id, Name = p.Name})
                                .ToList()
```

This can have huge performance benefits, if youre database has an index for these columns.

Comment: The difference between a defined type and an anonymous type is not explained.

Answer (score 0):

Use ".Select( s => new { s.X, s.Y, ... } )" method to select required columns.

You can specify a type to use results out of the current method: ".Select( s => new YourType(s.X, s.Y, ...) ).ToList()". It will produce List<YourType>.